# Sql server: Join two tables and select multiple column values with subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server

Table `OpenPO`

| Shopping_Cart_No | Goods_Recipient_Emp_ID | accassgnmtownerid |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1001958413 | 160213 | 65658 |
| 1001661570 | 61875 | 61855 |

Table `Employee`

| employee_number | Email |
| --- | --- |
| 160213 | Quentin_Walker@gmail.com |
| 61875 | Mihaela_Balseanu@gmail.com |
| 65658 | siva@gmail.com |
| 61855 | mohan@gmail.com |

I have these two tables, both are linked by the `employee_number` column.

I want to display data as shown below .

Expected result

| Goods_Recipient_Email | Goods_Recipient_Emp_ID | accassgnmtownerid | accassgnmtownerid_Email |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Quentin_Walker@gmail.com | 160213 | 65658 | siva@gmail.com |
| Mihaela_Balseanu@gmail.com | 61875 | 61855 | mohan@gmail.com |

Tried with left join and able to compare and select only one email column Goods_Recipient_Emp_ID or op.accassgnmtownerid

```
SELECT 
    op.Goods_Recipient_Emp_ID, op.accassgnmtownerid, 
    te.Email AS accassgnmtownerid_Email
FROM 
    OpenPO op
LEFT JOIN 
    Employee te ON te.Employee_Number = op.Goods_Recipient_Emp_ID
```

Tried with subquery for `accassgnmtownerid_Email`, but it didn't work out.

Can we apply subquery for `accassgnmtownerid_Email` or is there any other solution?

Comment: Someone asked a very similar question just 15 minutes ago, but I can't find it now...

Comment: I only asked, it was incomplete, by mistake clicked enter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to join the table `employee` twice, using two different aliases.

For example:

```
select
  r.email as Goods_Recipient_Email,
  o.Goods_Recipient_Emp_ID,
  o.accassgnmtownerid,
  a.email as accassgnmtownerid_Email
from openpo o
join employee r on r.employee_number = o.Goods_Recipient_Emp_ID
join employee a on a.employee_number = o.accassgnmtownerid
```

Answer (score 1):

Other than joining the tables for each Email, you can also use a correlated subquery for each, such as

```
select 
  (select Email from Employee e where e.employee_number = po.Goods_Recipient_Emp_ID) Goods_Recipient_Email,
  po.Goods_Recipient_Emp_ID,
  po.accassgnmtownerid,
  (select Email from Employee e where e.employee_number = po.accassgnmtownerid) accassgnmtownerid_Email
from OpenPO po;
```

Comment: that looks actually very bad,, what would be the performance of that in large tables, it would be worse than joins

Comment: @nbk looks are obviously deceiving - remember SQL is a declarative language - the correlated subquery would be an outer join so it would very much depend on the data / requirements. For a 1-1 match for the joins though I'd bet the execution plans would be identical.

Comment: FYI performance with the same scenario on a 1.6m row table is identical - identical CPU, identical IO.

Comment: @Stu I would guess the execution plan is identical to the query I wrote. Just two NLJ.